# bash: write first n lines of each file in subdir to new directory with same filenames

Tags: bash, xargs

This python 3 code does exactly what I want

```py
from pathlib import Path
def minify(src_dir:Path, dest_dir:Path, n: int):
    """Write first n lines of each file f in src_dir to dest_dir/f"""
    dest_dir.mkdir(exist_ok=True)
    for path in src_dir.iterdir():
        new = [x.rstrip() for x in list(path.open().readlines())][:n]
        dest_path = dest_dir.joinpath(path.name)
        dest_path.open('w').write('\n'.join(new))
```

Is there a way to do the same in bash, maybe with `xargs`?

```
ls src_dist/* | xargs head -10
```

displays what I need, but I don't know how to route that output to the proper file.

Comment: definltely possible, something like `for f in src_dist/* ; do sed -n '1,10p' "$f" > otherDir/"$f".hdr ; done` will get you started. Post a new Q if you get stuck on you `bash` solution. Make sure to set up a test dir structure while figuring this out. Very easy to mess up your core files. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You need to instrument a mini shell scriptlet to do it:

> Simple version supporting "sane" filenames (no spaces, etc)

```
ls src_dist/* | xargs -I% bash -c 'head -10 % > dst_dir/$(basename %)'
```

> More complex CLI, supporting e.g. filenames with spaces:

```
find src_dist/* -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I% bash -c $'head -10 "%" > "dst_dir/$(basename \'%\')"'
```

Comment: You should probably replace `ls` with `printf '%s\n'`; see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh

next() {
[[ -s stack ]] && main
end
}

main() {
line=$(ed -s stack < edprint+.txt)
head -10 "${line}" > ./newdir/newfile
ed -s stack < edpop+.txt
next
}

end() {
rm -v ./stack
rm -v ./edprint+.txt
rm -v ./edpop+.txt
exit 0
}

find . -type -f > stack

cat >> edprint+.txt << EOF
1
q
EOF

cat >> edpop+.txt << EOF
1d
wq
EOF

next
```